# Bound on signal after passing through 2 pole lowpass filter

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, filters

I am trying to implement some simple digital filters for a software synthesizer.

This link seemed like a good start, and many things reference it: http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

Problem is, both the frequency response formulas (H(s) = 1 / (s^2 + s/Q + 1)) and the recursive formulas don't seem to give normalized values, and passing a signal from -1 to 1 through them sometimes results in a signal with values >4, which breaks everything else.

Wikipedia has some slightly different formulas for the frequency response here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor
[image]

These already make more sense to me, as this can never be over 1 for any cutoff frequency, and so scales with the cutoff frequency. At least that would be my intuition, compared to the previous one.

I can't find a version of this in recursive formulas though, and I'm not even sure whether I'm diagnosing the problem right. Are those formulas from the Audio cookbook supposed to go outside the range, and if yes, how can I deal with that? Is this a (simple) issue of normalizing, or is it something more complex (Gibbs phenomenon)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for your question and area of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first expression for the transfer function is normalized in the sense $\omega_0=1$. In your second expression for the transfer function the substitution $s\rightarrow s/\omega_0$ has been made. What you experience is perfectly normal, there is nothing wrong. If $Q=1/\sqrt{2}$ you have a Butterworth response. Even though $|H(j\Omega)|\leq 1$, the output will/can exceed $\pm 1$ because of nonlinear phase. After you do the bilinear transformation and look at the resulting difference equation you will find that you can construct input sequences that clearly exceeds 1. What is normally done is to apply some input gain such that the output (and the states) of the filter never or very seldom exceeds $\pm 1$

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there any way to calculate this input gain?

Comment: Yes, there are difference scaling strategies. You can find them described in most DSP books I guess. However, what I do personally is just to process some representative data through my filter in e.g. Matlab and look at the output (and possibly internal variables) in a graph and get a feel for how much the input gain should be. If later on it turns out to be not enough because of some extreme/crazy input signal you would not have dreamed of the gain can always be lowered.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to niaren's answer:
Summing up the absolute of the impulse response gives you the upper bound for the gain.
Look here for more detail:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded-input,_bounded-output_stability